# Some cells are not visible when using Apache POI - Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

When developing a program using Apache POI, there was a problem. After reading the file, some cells disappear in some rows of the Excel spreadsheet. Does anyone know why this can occur and how to fix it? I'm using Apache POI version 3.17.

Part of the Excel table that I need to parse

[image]

An iterator, which shows that some cells are not readable

[image]

UPD 1:
Part of the code

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/schedule/" + fileName));

    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

    while (rowIterator.hasNext())
    {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();

        int rowNum = row.getRowNum();

        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

        int cellNumber = -1;

        while (cellIterator.hasNext())
        {
            cellNumber++;

            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

            CellType cellType = cell.getCellTypeEnum();

            switch (cellType)
            {
                case STRING:
                    if (checkGroupCellPlus(cell.getStringCellValue()))
                    {
                        Group = cell.getStringCellValue();

                        Main._Log.info("Группа " + Group + " подана на разбор");

                        groupId++;

                        groupDao.Insert(groupId, Group);

                        Iterator<Row> rowIteratorSchedule = sheet.iterator();

                        Row rowSchedule = rowIteratorSchedule.next();

                        for (int i=0; i < rowNum+1; i++)
                        {
                            rowSchedule = rowIteratorSchedule.next();
                        }

                        Integer classTime = 1;
                        Short dayOfWeek = 0;
                        Short numberOfWeek = 1;

                        while (rowSchedule.getRowNum() < 74)
                        {

                            rowSchedule = rowIteratorSchedule.next();

                            String subject = "";
                            String subjectType = "";
                            String teacher = "";
                            String classroom = "";
                            String teacherName = "";
                            String teacherSername = "";
                            String teacherSecondName = "";

                            Iterator<Cell> cellIteratorSchedule = rowSchedule.iterator();

                            Cell cellSchedule = cellIteratorSchedule.next();

                            String day = cellSchedule.getStringCellValue();

                            switch(day.toLowerCase())
                            {
                                case("понедельник"):
                                    dayOfWeek = 1;
                                    break;
                                case("вторник"):
                                    dayOfWeek = 2;
                                    break;
                                case("среда"):
                                    dayOfWeek = 3;
                                    break;
                                case("четверг"):
                                    dayOfWeek = 4;
                                    break;
                                case("пятница"):
                                    dayOfWeek = 5;
                                    break;
                                case("суббота"):
                                    dayOfWeek = 6;
                                    break;
                            }

                            /**Integer cellNumber1 = cellNumber;
                            if (numberOfWeek == 2)
                                cellNumber1 = cellSchedule.getColumnIndex();*/

                            for (int i=0; i < cellNumber; i++)
                            {
                                cellSchedule = cellIteratorSchedule.next();
                            }

                            switch (cellSchedule.getCellTypeEnum())
                            {
                                case STRING:
                                    if (!cellSchedule.getStringCellValue().toLowerCase().
                                            replaceAll("[^A-Za-zА-Яа-я]", "").equals("") &&
                                            !cellSchedule.getStringCellValue().toLowerCase().equals("день") &&
                                            !cellSchedule.getStringCellValue().toLowerCase().equals("самостоятельных")
                                            && !cellSchedule.getStringCellValue().toLowerCase().equals("занятий") &&
                                            !cellSchedule.getStringCellValue().toLowerCase().equals("военная") &&
                                            !cellSchedule.getStringCellValue().toLowerCase().equals("подготовка") &&
                                            !cellSchedule.getStringCellValue().toLowerCase().
                                                    equals("военная подготовка") &&
                                            !cellSchedule.getStringCellValue().toLowerCase().
                                                    equals("занятия по адресу:") && !cellSchedule.getStringCellValue().
                                            toLowerCase().equals("ул. М.Пироговская, д.1"))
                                    {
                                        subject = cellSchedule.getStringCellValue();
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case NUMERIC:
                                    Double subject1 = cellSchedule.getNumericCellValue();
                                    subject = subject1.toString();
                            }
                            cellSchedule = cellIteratorSchedule.next();

                                switch (cellSchedule.getCellTypeEnum())
                                        {
                                            case STRING:
                                                if (!cellSchedule.getStringCellValue().toLowerCase().
                                                        replaceAll("[^A-Za-zА-Яа-я]", "").equals(""))
                                                {
                                                    subjectType = cellSchedule.getStringCellValue();
                                                }
                                                break;

                                            case NUMERIC:
                                                Double subjectType1 = cellSchedule.getNumericCellValue();
                                                subjectType = subjectType1.toString();
                                                break;
                                        }

                            cellSchedule = cellIteratorSchedule.next();

                            switch (cellSchedule.getCellTypeEnum())
                            {
                                case STRING:
                                    if (!cellSchedule.getStringCellValue().toLowerCase().
                                            replaceAll("[^A-Za-zА-Яа-я]", "").equals(""))
                                    {
                                        teacher = cellSchedule.getStringCellValue();
                                    }
                                    break;

                                case NUMERIC:
                                    Double teacher1 = cellSchedule.getNumericCellValue();
                                    teacher = teacher1.toString();
                                    break;
                            }

                            cellSchedule = cellIteratorSchedule.next();

                            switch (cellSchedule.getCellTypeEnum())
                            {
                                case STRING:
                                    if (!cellSchedule.getStringCellValue().toLowerCase().
                                            replaceAll("[^A-Za-zА-Яа-я]", "").equals(""))
                                    {
                                        classroom = cellSchedule.getStringCellValue();
                                    }
                                    break;

                                case NUMERIC:
                                    Double classroom1 = cellSchedule.getNumericCellValue();
                                    classroom = classroom1.toString();
                                    break;
                            }

                                if (teacher.matches("[А-Я]([а-я]{1,})\\s[А-Я]\\.[А-Я]\\."))
                                {

                                    teacherSecondName = teacher.substring(0, teacher.indexOf(" "));
                                    teacher = teacher.replaceFirst(teacherSecondName, "");
                                    teacherName = teacher.substring(0, teacher.indexOf("."));
                                    teacher = teacher.replaceFirst(teacherName, "");
                                    teacher = teacher.replaceFirst("\\.", "");
                                    teacherSername = teacher.substring(0, teacher.indexOf("."));
                                }
                                else if (!teacher.contains(".")) teacherSecondName = teacher;


                               Main._Log.info("Разобрана запись " + fileName + " " + Group + " " + subject + " " + subjectType + " " + teacherSecondName + " " + dayOfWeek + " " + numberOfWeek + " " + classTime + " " + classroom);

                                if (!teacherSecondName.equals("") || !subject.equals("") || !subjectType.equals("") ||
                                        !classroom.equals(""))
                                {
                                    teacherDao.Insert(teacherId, teacherName, teacherSername, teacherSecondName,
                                            null, null);

                                    subjectDao.Insert(subjectId, subject, teacherId);

                                    classroomDao.Insert(classroomId, classroom, null);

                                    subjectTypeDao.Insert(subjectTypeId, subjectId, subjectType);

                                    scheduleDao.Insert(scheduleId, classTime, classroomId, subjectId, dayOfWeek,
                                            numberOfWeek);

                                    teacherId++;
                                    subjectId++;
                                    classroomId++;
                                    subjectTypeId++;
                                    scheduleId++;
                                }

                                if (numberOfWeek == 1)
                                    numberOfWeek++;
                                else if (numberOfWeek == 2)
                                {
                                    numberOfWeek = 1;
                                    classTime++;
                                }

                                if (classTime == 7)
                                    classTime = 1;
                        }

                    }
                    break;

                case NUMERIC:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @AxelRichter At this point, I do not read anything. This is the screen of all the cells in the line in the iterator

Comment: @AxelRichter Add a code

Comment: [The CellIterator will only return the cells defined in the file, which is largely those with values or stylings, but it depends on Excel](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterate+over+cells%2C+with+control+of+missing+%2F+blank+cells).

Comment: @AxelRichter This was the question whether this could be somehow corrected, are there any options why it is impossible to get these cells from Excel

Answer (score 3):

This is by design done by Microsoft in the Excel file format, Excel stores Cells sparsely, i.e. only the ones that are defined, not empty ones between existing cells.

Consequently there is no plan to change this in Apache POI. Your code needs to adjust for that, Row.getCell() will return null for such Cells. The iterator will not return those empty Cells.

When iterating, you can use [Cell.getColumnIndex()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getColumnIndex--) to see where in the row you are instead of doing the counting yourself via `cellNumber++`

Comment: This is actually a really good answer. I've been spending hours to solve the issue with hidden cell, and we should not count it is the best answer.